# How to insert 2 rows in the same table with info from 1 registration form

Tags: php, mysql

I am going to explain as detailed as possible what I am trying to do to see if I can get any help; I am new at programming, but I am trying to learn as much as possible. I am using PHP and MySql.

I have 2 initial tables. The first one describes the department; the second one describes the sections for each of those departments.

```
| dep_id | department |        | sec_id | section     | dep_id  | 
|:--------------------|        |:-------------------------------|
|   1    | Orchestra  |        |   1    |  Violin     |   1     | 
|   2    | Band       |        |   2    |  Viola      |   1     |
|   3    | Choir      |        |   3    |  Cello      |   1     |
|   4    | EFOM       |        |   4    |  Flute      |   2     |
                               |   5    |  Percussion |   2     |
                               |   6    |  Oboe       |   2     |
                                        ....and so on....
```

Now, I am trying to have a registration form that will allow people to choose at least 1 department and 1 section, which is really easy to do for a beginner like me. The problem comes when there are people who belong to 1 department and 2 different sections, or who belong to 2 departments and 2 sections. My idea is to store all the personal info in a table and then store in a different table the info about the department and section that each person belongs to. My problem is that I can't figure it out for the life of me how to insert 2 different rows of data in this table during the registration process. 1 row is easy to do, but the second row I don't know since I can't put 2 INSERT INTO queries (1 for each row) right next to each other..

```
|   id   | student_id  | sec_id  |  dep_id  | 
|:-------|-------------|---------|----------| 
|   1    |     1       |   1     |    1     |<---- student 1 row 1
|   2    |     1       |   6     |    2     |<---- student 1 row 2(How do I insert it?)
|   3    |     2       |   3     |    1     |
|   4    |     3       |   4     |    2     |
|   5    |     3       |   6     |    2     |
```

Maybe I am doing this wrong? Is there a better way to do this? If I am doing this right, how do I insert the second row?

I have tried to use something like this, but it looks ugly and inefficient... it also adds the wrong info...

```
 if(!empty($department1) && empty($department2) && !empty($section1) && empty($section2)){
     $query = "INSERT INTO student_dep_section (student_id, dep_section_id, dep_id) VALUES ('$student_id', '$section1', '$department1')";
     mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('There was a problem with your query. Please, contact website administrator.');                           
 }
 if(!empty($department1) && empty($department2) && !empty($section1) && !empty($section2)){
     $query = "INSERT INTO student_dep_section (student_id, dep_section_id, dep_id) VALUES ('$student_id', '$section2', '$department1')";
     mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('There was a problem with your query. Please, contact website administrator.');                  
 }
if(!empty($department2) && !empty($section1) && empty($section2)){
    $query = "INSERT INTO student_dep_section (student_id, dep_section_id, dep_id) VALUES ('$student_id', '$section1', '$department2')";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('There was a problem with your query. Please, contact website administrator.');   
}
if(!empty($department2) && !empty($section1) && !empty($section2)){
    $query = "INSERT INTO student_dep_section (student_id, dep_section_id, dep_id) VALUES ('$student_id', '$section2', '$department2')";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('There was a problem with your query. Please, contact website administrator.');   
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you use to insert records to your table

Comment: I just typed the code where the question is... It looks like really ugly code @Jelle Keizer! There has to be a better and efficient way to do this.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please [check this link](http://bobby-tables.com) for an explanation about what they are and how to prevent them.

Comment: Do you have an example of your form you can post? And how do you arrive at the variables like `$department1` & `$department2`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class that may help clean up your code a bit. Without your form and such, it's hard to fully answer your question.

```
class SaveDepartment
    {
        protected   $database;

        public  function __construct($database)
            {
                $this->database =   $database;
            }

        public function execute()
            {
                // However these are determined, set those here.
                $department1    =   '';
                $department2    =   '';
                $section1       =   '';
                $section2       =   '';

                if(!empty($department1) && empty($department2)) {
                        if(!empty($section1)) {
                                $values =   (!empty($section2))? $section2 : $section1;
                                $this->Write(array('student_id'=>$student_id,'dep_section_id'=>$values,'dep_id'=>$department1));
                            }
                    }

                if(!empty($department2) && !empty($section1)) {
                        $values =   (!empty($section2))? $section2 : $section1;
                        $this->Write(array('student_id'=>$student_id,'dep_section_id'=>$values,'dep_id'=>$department1));
                    }
            }

        protected   function Write($vals = array('student_id'=>'','dep_section_id'=>'','dep_id'=>''), $error = "There was a problem with your query. Please, contact website administrator.")
            {
                if(!empty($vals['student_id'])) {
                        foreach($vals as $key => $value) {
                                // Sanitize your inputs
                                $array[$key]    =   "'".htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES)."'";
                            }
                        // Implode your array
                        $vars   =   implode(",",$array);
                        // Insert into the sql statement
                        $sql    =   "INSERT INTO student_dep_section (student_id, dep_section_id, dep_id) VALUES ($vars)";
                        // Run query
                        mysqli_query($this->database, $sql) or die($error);
                    }
            }
    }

// Initialize class
$depApp =   new SaveDepartment($dbc);
// Run your execution script
$depApp->execute();
```